# Scan output of a command for a certain character, if that character is '-', perform certain actions?

Tags: linux, bash

**Goal**: To highlight the entire line of my following output that has a directory without execute permissions for other.

How can I detect in my "other" column if the 3rd permission bit is either a - or T/t and based on that, highlight entire line? I know the highlight command, it's tput rmso I think, that's not the problem. It's the detection and manipulation that is.

Hey, so I'm working on a script that will list directories in long format, then format that output. Here is the output of my program:

```
  Owner   Group   Other   Filename
  -----   -----   -----   --------
d r w x   r - x   r - x   /
d r w x   r - x   r - x   home
d r w x   r - x   r - x   eveo
d r w x   r - x   r - x   Desktop
d r w x   r - x   r - x   scripts
```

Everything works as expected so far except for one thing. Here is my code.

```
if [ ! -d $1 ]
   then
      echo dirpath: $1 is not a valid directory name >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ $# = 2 ]
      then
      echo Usage: dirpath [ dir-name ] >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ $# = 0 ]
      then
      echo Usage: dirpath [ dir-name ] >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ $# = 1 ]
      then
         echo "  Owner   Group   Other   Filename"
         echo "  -----   -----   -----   --------"
         echo $PWD | sed 's/\//\n/g' > file1

         sed '1s/?*/\//' file1 > file2

         permissions1=$(ls -ld | cut -c1-4 | sed 's/./& /g')
         permissions2=$(ls -ld | cut -c5-7 | sed 's/./& /g')
         permissions3=$(ls -ld | cut -c8-10 | sed 's/./& /g')

         while read line
            do 
            echo -e "$permissions1  $permissions2  $permissions3  $line"
         done < file2

      exit 0
   else
      echo Usage: dirpath [ dir-name ] >&2
      exit 1
fi
```

**EDIT: FINISHED IT MYSELF :D**

UPDATED SOURCE:

```
if [ ! -d $1 ]
   then
      echo dirpath: $1 is not a valid directory name >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ $# = 2 ]
      then
      echo Usage: dirpath [ dir-name ] >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ $# = 0 ]
      then
      echo Usage: dirpath [ dir-name ] >&2
      exit 1
   elif [ $# = 1 ]
      then
         echo "  Owner   Group   Other   Filename"
         echo "  -----   -----   -----   --------"

         normaldir="$PWD"
         cd $1
         targetdir="$PWD"
         cd $normaldir

         temp1=/tmp/$$temp1
         temp2=/tmp/$$temp2

         echo "$targetdir" | sed 's/\//\n/g' > $temp1

         sed '1s/?*/\//' $temp1 > $temp2

         pathname=

         while read line
               do 

               if [ "$pathname" = "/" ]
                 then
                 pathname="$pathname$line"
               else
                 pathname="$pathname/$line" 
               fi

               permissions1=$(ls -ld "$pathname" | cut -c1-4 | sed 's/./& /g')
               permissions2=$(ls -ld "$pathname" | cut -c5-7 | sed 's/./& /g')
               permissions3=$(ls -ld "$pathname" | cut -c8-10 | sed 's/./& /g')

               otherexec=$(ls -ld "$pathname" | cut -c10 )

               if [ "$otherexec" = "-" ] || [ "$otherexec" = "T" ]
                  then
                  tput smso
               fi
                  ############################################################
                  echo -e "$permissions1  $permissions2  $permissions3  $line"
                  ############################################################
               if [ "$otherexec" = "-" ] || [ "$otherexec" = "T" ]
                  then
                  tput rmso
               fi

         done < $temp2

         #rm $tempfile1 file2

      exit 0
   else
      echo Usage: dirpath [ dir-name ] >&2
      exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Oh, is that the check mark thing? Legit didn't even notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to check execute permission in Bash is

```
for file in `find $pathname -perm /111` ; do
    echo "$file is executable/n"
done
```

find is incredibly useful, the -print0 option terminates each line with a null character instead of a newline.

Comment: No, it just had to check the character.